# count rows in a text file

Tags: c#

I have the following rows in a text file and I need to know how many rows end with a Y and how many end with a N.

there is a space after the Y and after the N.

The faster the better as it might contain a million or so rows.(so I would prefer not to loop through every line)

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you experiencing? And of course, **what is your question**?

Comment: What is a C# Text File? Is that different from a normal text file?

Answer (score 7):

Well you're going to *have* to loop through every line, certainly. There's really no getting around that. You could then use LINQ to count them reasonably easily:

```
var query = File.ReadLines("file.txt")
                .Select(line => new { Y = line.EndsWith("Y ") ? 1 : 0,
                                      N = line.EndsWith("N ") ? 1 : 0 })
                .Aggregate(new { Y = 0, N = 0 },
                           (current, next) => new { Y = current.Y + next.Y,
                                                    N = current.N + next.N });

var yCount = query.Y;
var nCount = query.N;
```

If there isn't *exactly one* space after the Y / N, change it to use `Trim()` instead... for example:

```
var query = File.ReadLines("file.txt")
                .Select(line => line.Trim())
                .Select(line => new { Y = line.EndsWith("Y") ? 1 : 0,
                                      N = line.EndsWith("N") ? 1 : 0 })
// remainder of code as before
```

This will iterate through the whole file just once, counting as it goes. Admittedly it's creating a *lot* of objects, but the GC is pretty good. It *doesn't* pull the whole file into memory, or read it twice.

Comment: Since there is whitespace at the end of the lines you have to `Trim` them before checking ;)

Comment: @Tobias: How do you know there's whitespace at the end of lines? (`File.ReadLines` doesn't include the line separator, if that's what you were thinking of...)

Comment: Second paragraph in the question states that "there is a space after the Y and after the N"

Comment: Checking for `"Y "` and `"N "` should be enough.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: At least as long as the mentioned paragraph is actually accurate (which isn't certain, hence the proposal of the safer approach).

Comment: If you trim the lines, you should alter your `EndsWith(...)` accordingly (regarding spaces). Just saying...