# Count rows in a text file that meet a condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 scripts from Microsoft's LINQ samples. The first one will count all the lines of text in a text file. The second one will list only the records that meet a certain condition.

How can I apply the same condition to the first counting script?

```
string[] records = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Reports\MyReports.txt");
try
{
    int numberOfRecords = records.Count();
    Console.WriteLine(
        "There are {0} records in the text file.",
        numberOfRecords);
}
catch (OverflowException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The count is too large to store as an Int32.");
    Console.WriteLine("Try using the LongCount() method instead.");
}

var targetLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Reports\MyReports.txt")
          .Select((x, i) => new { Line = x, LineNumber = i })
          .Where( x => x.Line.Contains(".dwg"))
          .ToList();

foreach (var line in targetLines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", line.LineNumber, line.Line);
            }

            File.WriteAllText (@"C:\Reports\MyReports2.txt", Util.ToCsvString (targetLines));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [count rows in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956293/count-rows-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I apply the same condition to the first counting script?

Like this:

```
int numberOfRecords = records.Count(x => x.Line.Contains(".dwg"));
```

The idea is to change the method that you are calling: instead of the parameterless<sup>*</sup> one, call the [overload that takes a condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

<sup>*</sup> Technically, `Count()` takes a single parameter - the list to which it is applied. The parameter is not visible, because it is passed implicitly using the extension method syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have spent an embarrassing amount of time on this today.